# Auto meta tag descsription and keywords

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I have some code for auto meta tag title, but I need to make it work for description and keywords, it's annoying to input the title every time on meta

this code will copying the product title to meta title, how i can apply to the description and keyword

```
 <file path="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[{% if error_meta_title[language.language_id] %}]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[                
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $("input[name='product_description[{{ language.language_id }}][name]']").keyup(function() {
                        $("input[name='product_description[{{ language.language_id }}][meta_title]']").val($(this).val());
                    });
                });
          </script>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This should fill description and keywords fields.

```
<file path="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[{% if error_meta_title[language.language_id] %}]]></search>
        <add position="before"><![CDATA[                
            <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {
                    $("input[name='product_description[{{ language.language_id }}][name]']").keyup(function() {
                    $("input[name='product_description[{{ language.language_id }}][meta_title]']").val($(this).val());
                    $("#input-meta-keyword{{ language.language_id }}").val($(this).val());
                    $("#input-meta-description{{ language.language_id }}").val($(this).val());

                });
            });
    </script>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```